# New Facebook Graph API - Embed photo in

Tags: facebook, api

I have some trouble in performing an embedding post (especially images) using the new facebook API for Instagram.

Actually I have to perform the following operation: from the account page I need to get the latest 6 post and visualize them on a web page that I own. Clearly this solution must be automated, meaning that if something change on instagram changes must reflect on the web site.

I have take a look to the documentation but I found it very confusing (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed) and it seems that there are no ways to get a list of post for a given user in a simple way (I check out the oEmbed option, but always need a post url that I don't have inside an automatic procedure). Also the API Instagram Basic Display seems to need ids to run, but I cannot figure out how to obtain them.

Resuming I need a series of calls to the API to obtain a list of n post for a specific user. Is that possible now? What call should I perform to achieve this goal?

Comment: oEmbed is a mechanism for embedding specific posts, the URL of which you already know. It has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with fetching the latest posts.

Comment: You need to get an access token, and then you can get a list of media items from this endpoint, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user/media The `{user-id}` part can be replaced with [`me`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/me), the API will automatically figure out which account that is supposed to refer to, based on the access token.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using simple embed from Instragram API things will get tricky.

I have been testing in local mode and have no problems with the link generated by Instragram.

The problem is that once you are live as far as I understand you will to need to have:

- Yourself registered as a Facebook Developer Account.
- Create a Facebook app.
- The Oembed product created in dashboard.
- The Acces Token from your developer account. **Config->advance->Token**
- And the most tricky one: **live mode**. Which implies verifying your account https://business.facebook.com/settings/security/business_verification.

As far as I understood In documentation the simple embed link will change from:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/shortCode/
```

to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/shortCode/acces_token={appId + client-token}
```

However, I haven't been able to change my account to live since I get prompted for documentation -which I don't have- that confirms that I own the enterprise. Thus, not being to able to correctly test these steps in live server.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely being prompted for documentation because the Facebook App uses one or more other products that DO require it.  oEmbed by itself does not require business verification in order to go into Live Mode.

A quick and dirty solution is to make a new Facebook App, put that app in Live Mode, and just use that app for oEmbed.